# Leader election initialisation for multiple roles in clustered environment

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am currently working with an implementation based on:

```
org.springframework.integration.support.leader.LockRegistryLeaderInitiator
```

Having multiple candidate roles so that only one application instance within the cluster is elected as leader for each role. During initialisation of the cluster if autoStartup property is set to true the first application instance that is initialised will be elected as leader for all roles. This is something that we want to avoid and instead have a fair distribution of the lead roles across the cluster.

One possible solution on the above might be that when the cluster is ready and properly initialised then invoke an endpoint that will execute:

```
lockRegistryLeaderInitiator.start()
```

For all instances in the cluster so that the election process starts and the roles are fairly distributed across instances. One drawback on that is that this needs to be part of the deployment process, adding somehow complexity.

What is the proposed best practice on the above? Are there any plans for additional features related? For example to autoStartup the leader election only when X application instances are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look into the [Spring Cloud Bus](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus) project. I don't know its details, but looks like your idea about `autoStartup = false` for all the `LockRegistryLeaderInitiator` instances and their startup by some distributed event is the way to go.

Not sure what we can do for you from the Spring Integration perspective, but it fully feels like not its responsibility and all the coordinations and rebalancing should be done via some other tool. Fortunately all our Spring projects can be used together as a single platform.

I think with the Bus you even really can track the number of instances joined the cluster and decide your self when and how to publish `StartLeaderInitiators` event.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Artem. Adding a new technology in your stack provides extra infrastructure complexity that you always want to balance.
The only reason I am asking if there are future plans to support it is that since the LockRegistryLeaderInitiator is backed by a LockRegistry implemented over JDBC, Zookeeper, Redis and Gemfire. Wouldn't it make sense to also configure the start of the election process based on the number of instances that joined the cluster backed by the exact same technologies? Btw I am fully covered by your answer.

Comment: Yeah... I guess for that purpose you can implement something like one more leader election called `master`. So, on start of the application only one master is going to be selected and it will ping some shared store (JDBC?) for registered members and after meeting a desired condition you can publish a distributed command to start all other leader elections for target business functions. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: It definitely makes sense and more or less was my initial thought. Just wondering if this can be abstracted, but it's ok since there is a way handle it.

Comment: Might be. For example an existing `MessageGroupStore` can be used to track members in the generic role as a group for them. A bit awkward, but still...

Comment: Thinking out loud, how about persisting (with TTL / expiry) the candidate's id and role via a CandidateRegistry at the shared storage upon initialisation. The LockRegistryLeaderInitiator will just need to poll / refresh TTL this state and actually start only when the condition is satisfied. For example 4 candidates are found.

Comment: Might be... But how about something simple like `delayed start` for candidates? At least this is what Apache Kafka suggests for its initial rebalancing: `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms`. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs. I understand that you would like to have a condition based on the number of members, but still...

Comment: The only thing with delay is that it does not provide anyhow guarantees that the candidate will be alone in the cluster doing self-election. If all candidates have the same delay then we end-up with the first initialised candidate to eventually take all roles. Not?

Comment: The delay should be relative to the first initialised candidate. So given that you estimate your cluster initialisation time to be X seconds it can work as well. But still based on an estimation.

Comment: Correct. So, let's come back to our original idea about polling some shared store to determine the state that we are ready to start leader election. For this purpose the JDBC Inbound Channel Adapter and Control Bus are good candidates. The JDBC Outbound Channel Adapter should be good one for registering candidate in that store.

Comment: The delayed start as long as it is persisted in the shared store can definitely work. The same applies also for the CandidateRegistry. This abstraction over the leader election initiation will be very useful and it's up to you to decide on that.

Comment: Well, you again can come up with the `delayed leader election` start with one more leader election. So, you start app, only one leader and it sends a message to start all other initiators via Spring Integration `Delayer` EIP.

Answer (score 1):

It would be relatively easy with the Zookeeper `LeaderInitiator` because you could check in zookeeper for the instance count before starting it.

It's not so easy with the lock registry because there's no inherent information about instances; you would need some external mechanism (such as zookeeper, in which case, you might as well use ZK).

Or, you could use something like Spring Cloud Bus (with RabbitMQ or Kafka) to send a signal to all instances that it's time to start electing leadership.

Answer (score 0):

I find very simple approach to do this.
You could add scheduled task to each node which periodically tries to yield leaderships if node holds too many of them.

For example, if you have N nodes and 2*N roles and you want to achieve completely fair leadership distribution (each node tries to hold only two leaderships) you can use something like this:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FairLeaderDistributor {
    private final List<LeaderInitiator> initiators;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 300_000) // once per 5 minutes
    public void yieldExcessLeaderships() {
        initiators.stream()
                .map(LeaderInitiator::getContext)
                .filter(Context::isLeader)
                .skip(2) // keep only 2 leaderships
                .forEach(Context::yield);
    }
}
```

When all nodes will be up, you will *eventually* get completely fair leadership distribution.

You can also implement dynamic distribution based on current active node count if you use Zookeeper `LeaderInitiator` implementation.
Current number of participants can be easily retrieved from Curator `LeaderSelector::getParticipants` method.
You can get `LeaderSelector` with reflection from `LeaderInitiator.leaderSelector` field.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DynamicFairLeaderDistributor {
    final List<LeaderInitiator> initiators;

    @SneakyThrows
    private static int getParticipantsCount(LeaderInitiator leaderInitiator) {
        Field field = LeaderInitiator.class.getDeclaredField("leaderSelector");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        LeaderSelector leaderSelector = (LeaderSelector) field.get(leaderInitiator);
        return leaderSelector.getParticipants().size();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5_000)
    public void yieldExcessLeaderships() {
        int rolesCount = initiators.size();
        if (rolesCount == 0) return;

        int participantsCount = getParticipantsCount(initiators.get(0));
        if (participantsCount == 0) return;

        int maxLeadershipsCount = (rolesCount - 1) / participantsCount + 1;

        log.info("rolesCount={}, participantsCount={}, maxLeadershipsCount={}", rolesCount, participantsCount, maxLeadershipsCount);

        initiators.stream()
                .map(LeaderInitiator::getContext)
                .filter(Context::isLeader)
                .skip(maxLeadershipsCount)
                .forEach(Context::yield);
    }
}
```